# How can I use the service fabric actor model from MVC project?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I used the stateful actor template in visual studio 2015 to create a service fabric service. In the same solution I created an MVC app and in the about controller I attempted to copy the code from the sample client. When I run the web app and execute about action it just hangs. I don't get an exception or anything that indicates why it didn't work. Running the sample client console app where I got the code works just fine. Any suggestions on what may be wrong?

```
        public ActionResult About()
    {
        var proxy = ActorProxy.Create<IO365ServiceHealth>(ActorId.NewId(), "fabric:/O365Services");

        try
        {
            int count = 10;
            Console.WriteLine("Setting Count to in Actor {0}: {1}", proxy.GetActorId(), count);
            proxy.SetCountAsync(count).Wait(); /* Hangs here */

            Console.WriteLine("Count from Actor {0}: {1}", proxy.GetActorId(), proxy.GetCountAsync().Result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", ex.Message);
        }

        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I also tried creating MVC vNext web app and I get a different result. In this case I get an exception that states "The method or operation is not implemented".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the MVC app hosted within Service Fabric? If not then it won't be able to access Service Fabric information unless it's exposed in some way (e.g. through an OwinCommunicationListener on a service).